# Should I up-vote to a useful question/answer that has received enough up-vote?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Should I up-vote to a useful question/answer that has received enough up-vote?

My argument is this: Almost all posts were posted around the birth of the MSE, has received more up-vote. but a new good post does not receive more that 5 or 6 up-vote usually.

E.g. Should I up-vote for [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255384/272127)? of course it is useful, both answer and question.

Comment: How much upvote is enough for a good question?

Comment: It is _common_ that users up-vote at most 5 or 6 to a rather good question.

Comment: Whether I upvote something has nothing to do with how many votes it already has, or when the post first appeared. There are lots of good posts in here, sometimes one misses them the first time 'round. Even in areas I follow closely, sometimes I only find some gems years after they were posted.

Comment: Self-reference: this meta post has already received more than usual (5 or 6) votes. So should I upvote it?

Comment: Is it extremely good and useful, or good or rather good or ... ?

Answer (score 23):

When you see good quality content, vote it up. If and when you run into your votes limit for a month straight, you can start thinking about dividing your voting attention to new or old content.

One advice, when you do reach that point, which was given here on meta in the past (I do not recall who gave it though) was to read a post and assign is a mental score, and if it is below that score, vote it up. Sort of saying "Oh, this answer should have at least 20 votes", and then vote it up if it only has 16. Of course, don't downvote good content just because the score "is too high for your taste".

Comment: I upvoted when I saw “don’t downvote just because the score is too high for you”.

Comment: I didn't upvote this because it already has score ≥ 20.

Comment: @user21820: And you think that 20 points is enough for an answer like this?

Comment: Yup. In my opinion, having 23 upvotes and 0 downvotes (as of now) indicates clearly that there is negligible dissent on Meta to this proposal, so it is unlikely to swing the other way in the future. That's how I perceive it anyway. =)

Comment: @user21820: And you don't think that it should have a nice round score, like 50, or 100? :-D

Comment: Hah. I guess you think so. =D